# Error message LNK2019, unresolved external symbol _output referenced in function __tr0

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, c++

I've successfully compiled the simple addtwo function predefined in *Mathematica* as per: 
[MathLink dependencies: "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MLMain"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/mathlink-dependencies-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-mlmain)
I am now attempting to write an external function which calls a class I wrote earlier and returns a list of values using an output file called output.tm. The output file is as follows:

```cpp
void output P((double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, int, int));

:Begin:
:Function:       output
:Pattern:        output[x0_Real64, t0_Real64, tend_Real64, deltat_Real64, D_Real64, p_Real64, q_Real64, finallevel_Real64, nDIM_Integer32, iterations_Integer32]
:Arguments:      { x0, t0, tend, deltat, D, p, q, finallevel, nDIM, iterations }
:ArgumentTypes:  { Real64, Real64, Real64, Real64, Real64, Real64, Real64, Real64, Integer32, Integer32 }
:ReturnType:     Manual
:End:
```

The relevant part of my c++ code is given here:

```cpp
#include "mathlink.h"
using namespace std;
extern void output(MLINK mlp, double x0, double t0, double tend, double deltat, double D, double p, double q, double finallevel, int nDIM, int iterations);

class Solver()
{
etc. etc.
}
void output(MLINK mlp, double x0, double t0, double tend, double deltat, double D, double p, double q, double finallevel, int nDIM, int iterations)
{
    Solver s(x0, D, t0, tend, deltat, finallevel, p, q, nDIM);

    s.PropagationDelayDistributionSolver(iterations);

    MLPutReal64List(mlp, s.returntau(), iterations);
}
```

Where s.returntau returns an array of doubles from the class (again, the details aren't important). When I compile this code, I only get one error:

> Error 2 $\quad \quad$ error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _output referenced in function __tr0  C:\Users\SOM874\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PDS5\PDS5\output.obj $\quad \quad$ PDS5

I don't see anything wrong when I look at the output.c file but I am a novice, I wouldn't know what to look for. Is there anything wrong which jumps out at you? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several problems here: 1. the `:Pattern:` part of the template must be a Mathematica pattern that will match any call of the function from within Mathematica.  There's no such thing as `Real64` in Mathematica.  What you specify in `:ArgumentTypes:` a completely different thing, those are not patterns.  The possible values for that are documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/file.tm.html) and appear to be correct.

Comment: The second problem is what sakra has just posted so I won't repeat that.

Comment: And one more thing: in Mathematica, avoid names starting with capitals to make sure there's no collision with builtins.  Specifically: do not use `D`. It has a builtin meaning. Use something else with lowercase, like `dd`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is a linkage issue. The generated `output.tm.c` file is compiled a C code whereas "your code" is compiled as C++ code. Thus the function `output` will have C++ linkage while the function `__tr0` expects the function to have C linkage. In your C++ code, declare the function with C linkage using `extern "C"`, i.e.:

```
#include "mathlink.h"
using namespace std;
extern "C" void output(MLINK mlp, double x0, double t0, double tend, double deltat, double D, double p, double q, double finallevel, int nDIM, int iterations);
```

Comment: So in this case will I lose the C++ class functionality within the function? Will I have to rewrite the code so that it does not call a class?

Comment: No. The `extern "C"` makes the function `output` callable from both C and C++ code. In its implementation you are free to use C++ language features.